# IE clears upload file input

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, file-upload

We have a system written in .net web forms that allows people to upload their resume for job applications.  We average a few thousand a week and have been getting reports from around maybe 10 a week that cannot upload their resume.  We're told that they fill out the form, use the file input to select the resume on their computer and when they hit the submit button the file input is cleared out (which causes a validation error since resume is required).

It also appears that when people will respond to us with system info, they're always using different versions of IE.  We cannot reproduce the behavior and after googling the problem I found a thread here where someone said it was a bug in IE.

Does anyone know if this is true and if so, is there anything we as developers can do?  The only alternative I can think of is to swap out the asp.net file upload control with an ajax iframe uploader.  Has anyone run into this and know what we can do to reproduce the problem or fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: What control you use ? how do you upload the files ? do you have check the upload limits ? With out any code and real information's, you can get only philosophical answers

Comment: Indeed, which is very similar to the "not a real question" close reason - "*It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, **vague, incomplete**, overly broad, or rhetorical*"

Comment: I'd love to give more specifics but I've given all that we have.  As I already stated, it's a web form using a (native asp.net) file upload control and the errors so far are coming from IE.  The problem is that most users won't respond with any further details after initially reporting the error.  Yes, we check upload limits but when we have users who forward their resume, the file size is no where near the max file size.

Comment: @geoffswartz did you ever find the cause of this? Bizarrely we have some users with the same problem but we are unable to replicate.

Comment: What we did find was that if we got to the web site with the upload control by clicking on a link in gmail (again using IE) it would produce this problem.  We were consistently able to reproduce the problem this way and only this way.